# Android web service connection doesn't work after leaving app open for some time

Tags: java, android, connection

I am designing an app which needs to frequently make connection to a web service. It works fine whenever I use it but if I lets say leave it out for a while and make some coffee and come back and try to go to the activity(ies) which require the connection to the web service, it doesn't work and my service response returns null.

Is there any code I am maybe missing (quite new to android development) which makes the phone stay connected. However, I have a button which opens a web browser to open a link and that seems to work whenever. It is therefore I think it doesn't have to do with the internet connection.

Code here as requested:

```
    private String getIndividualProduct() throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String data = null;
    String methodname = "getProductById";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodname);

    request.addProperty("id", id);
    request.addProperty("shopId", shopId);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();

    MarshallDouble marshall = new MarshallDouble();
    marshall.register(envelope);

    ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

    Object resultsString = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

    data = resultsString.toString();

    return data;
}

private static SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    return envelope;

}
private static HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE() throws IOException {

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY, MAIN_REQUEST_URL, 60000);
    ht.debug = true;
    ht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");

    return ht;

}
```

Here is my activity code:

```
    private ArrayList<Product> readFile() throws Exception {

    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    FileReader in = new FileReader(cart);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in);

    String temp;
    String data = null;

    while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        try {

            WebService service = new WebService(temp, true);
            data = service.getValue();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast no_cnx = Toast.makeText(
                            Winkelwagen_activity.this,
                            "Error Connecting. Try again.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    no_cnx.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    no_cnx.show();

                    Intent back = new Intent(Winkelwagen_activity.this,
                            Main_activity.class);

                    startActivity(back);
                    Winkelwagen_activity.this.finish();

                }
            });
        }

        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(data, shopId, true);

        Product product = parser.getSingleProduct();
        if (product != null) {
            products.add(product);

        }

    }

    reader.close();
    in.close();

    return products;
}
```

Comment: _I think it doesn't have to do with the internet connection_ So likely it has to do with the code you didn't post... Maybe you can post it so we can take a look at it ;)

Comment: Android cleans up resources all the time and doesnt have long-running network activity / connections so most likely guess (see BackSlash's comment) is it's just Android doing it's thing

Comment: If thats true, then how come i can leave my facebook app open for 10 minutes and it still works? And @BackSlash , its quite a logn peice of code. lemme check if I can cut it down to help you out. But it seems that nothing (not to sound cocky) is wrong because it works normally even if i switch back and forth between activities. it's just when i leave it on for a few minutes